# strstr not working with needles shorter than 3 char

Tags: c, char, substring, c-strings, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char* findSequence(char s[], char ch, int n){

    int i;
    char*ptr;
    char needle[n];
    char*npdr=&needle;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){needle[i]=ch;}
     ptr = strstr(s,ndpr);
    printf("%s",ptr);
    return ptr;





}

int main()
{
    char stringa[]={"ciccciopasticcio"};
    char carattere='c';
    char*ptr;
    int n=3;

    ptr=findSequence(stringa, carattere,n);


    return 0;
}
```

This quick code, should search for a matching between a string and a needle of non set lenght, it works just fine with any n>=3 the problem is with 1 and 2 as n values.

watching the debug i noticed that the pointer npdr adds a second and third value to the sequence on his own example: n=2 needle="cc" npdr=address of needle[0] "cc@"

Do you have any ideas of why this is happening?

Comment: `char*npdr=&needle;` and `ptr = strstr(s,ndpr);` are wrong. Simply do `ptr = strstr(s,needle);`

Comment: And... `npdr` versus `ndpr` hmm, the code won't compile

Comment: Do you want this to find multiple occurrences (if there is more than one)? This looks like it will only indicate the first occurrence (if there is one.)

Answer (score 0):

The standard function `strstr` expects two pointers to strings. But you are calling the function passing an array as the second argument that does not contain a string - a sequence of characters terminated by the zero character `'\0'`

```
char needle[n];
char*npdr=&needle;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){needle[i]=ch;}
 ptr = strstr(s,ndpr);
```

So the code invokes undefined behavior.

Also this initialization

```
char*npdr=&needle;
```

is incorrect. The initialized pointer has the type `char *` while the initializing expression has the type `char ( * )[n]`. At least you need to write

```
char*npdr=needle;
```

You could declare the array like

```
char needle[n + 1];
```

and

```
needle[n] = '\0';
```

Pay attention to that the function should not output any message. It is the caller of the function will decide whether to output a message. Moreover this call of printf

```
printf("%s",ptr);
```

will invoke undefined behavior if the pointer `ptr` is equal to `NULL`.

The function itself should be declared the following way

```
char* findSequence(const char s[], char ch, size_t n);
```

That is the first parameter should be declared with the qualifier `const` because passed strings are not changed within the function. And the second parameter should have unsigned integer type `size_t` instead of the signed integer type `int`.

Also using a variable length array within the function makes the function unsafe.

The function can be defined using standard C string function `strchr` instead of the function `strstr`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * findSequence( const char s[], char ch, size_t n )
{
    const char *p = NULL;

    if (n != 0 && ch != '\0')
    {
        size_t count = 0;

        do
        {
            count = 0;

            p = strchr( s, ch );

            if (p)
            {
                s = p;
                do
                {
                    ++count;
                } while (*++s == ch);
            }
        } while (p != NULL && count != n);
    }

    return ( char * )p;
}

int main( void )
{
    char stringa[] = { "ciccciopasticcio" };
    char carattere = 'c';
    size_t n = 3;

    char *ptr = findSequence( stringa, carattere, n );

    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        puts( ptr );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
ccciopasticcio
```